# R nested for loops merge data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame in which each column is a time series of numbers (from 0 to 8) representing different behaviors during animal courtship. I would like to check if there is a pattern such as a given behavior is followed more frequently by another one. I have written a function that allow me to do calculate the frequencies of behaviours that follow a given behavior after a particular time interval:

```
> data[,3]
  [1]  1  1  1  1  7  7  3  3  7  3  1  1  8  1  3  3  3  5  1  1  4 ... 

neighbor <- function(DATA, BEHAVIOR, INTERVAL)
{
total=c(0)
tmp = data.frame(total=c(0:8),Freq=rep(0,9))
number_of_x = which(DATA == BEHAVIOR)

for(i in number_of_x){
              total = append(total,DATA[i+INTERVAL,])
}
tmp = merge(tmp,table(total), by=c("total"), all=T)
tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
subset(tmp, select = ncol(tmp))
}
```

So I run the function for say the third column, behavior 3, and next behavior in time (1) and I get what I want:

```
> neighbor(as.data.frame(data[,3], 3, 1]
Freq.y
0 0.01
1 0.71
2 0.01
3 0.21
4 0.01
5 0.04
6 0.01
7 0.02
8 0.00
```

Now I would like to use a similar function to obtain the frequencies for the nine behaviours. Something like:

```
neighborAll <- function(DATA, INTERVAL)
{
total=c(0)
tmp = data.frame(total=c(0:8),Freq=rep(0,9))
for(a in c(0:8)){
number_of_x = which(DATA == a)
for(i in number_of_x){
      total = c(total,DATA[i+INTERVAL,])
}
tmp=merge(tmp, table(total), by = c("total"), all=T)
tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
}
tmp[,3:9]
}

> neighborAll(as.data.frame(data[,3], 1)
```

I get:

```
Error in merge.data.frame(tmp, table(total), by = c("total"), all = T) : 
  there is already a column named ‘Freq.x’
```

Any ideas would be welcomed. Thanks in advance, Jose

Comment: A reproducible example will go a long way, I should reckon.

Comment: @lince, if you want answers you really should supply a reproducible example that can be copied and pasted into an R session (even if it fails). That may mean creating a simpler piece of code with dummy data, which can seem like a lot of work. However, I have found that preparing a question for stackoverflow is a useful discipline and several times I have found the answer myself without needing to post the question to SO. The code should be concise; get rid of everything not needed to understand the problem. My most recent question was justly criticised for not having a minimal enough example!

Comment: Rewriting is best; as the answers below show.  But the problem above could be fixed by either renaming the new column before merging, as the error message is telling you have several columns of the same name, or, I notice you don't take a subset of columns in the All version; it may be you're carrying around more columns than you want to each time, and they have the same name.

Comment: Aaron, you are right, if I add [suffixes=c("", ".x")] I can get rid of the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it weren't for getting the names right, each of these could be a one-liner.

```
neighbor <- function(DATA, BEHAVIOR, INTERVAL) {
  nbins <- 1+max(0, DATA, na.rm = TRUE)
  out <- tabulate(1+DATA[which(DATA==BEHAVIOR)+INTERVAL], nbins=nbins)
  names(out) <- 1:nbins - 1
  out
}

neighborAll <- function(DATA, INTERVAL) {
  out <- sapply(0:max(DATA, na.rm=TRUE), 
         function(BEHAVIOR) neighbor(DATA, BEHAVIOR, INTERVAL))
  colnames(out) <- 0:max(DATA, na.rm=TRUE)
  out
}

> x <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 1, 1 ,8, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1, 4)

> neighbor(x,3,1)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 0 3 0 1 0 1 0 

> neighborAll(x,1)
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 5 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 2 0
4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
8 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, your solution is clear, simple and very elegant. I have only added na.rm = TRUE in the max(DATA) of the second function. This forum is really useful and I am learning a lot from all you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you want this:

```
neighborAll <- function(DATA, INTERVAL, TABLE)
{
    for(i in 1:(nrow(TABLE) - 1))
    {
        neighbors <- DATA[which(DATA == i) + INTERVAL]
        tab <- table(neighbors)
        TABLE[TABLE$behavior %in% names(tab), i + 2] <- tab
    }
    return(TABLE)
}

x<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 1, 1 ,8, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1, 4)

behavior <- 0:8
n <- length(behavior)
tmp <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=n)
colnames(tmp) <- paste("freq", behavior, sep="")
freqtab <- data.frame(behavior, tmp)

neighborAll(x, 1, freqtab)
```